# $\| f \|_{L^1} > 0 $ is stronger than simply $f \neq 0$. But how much?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My question is: for a non-negative function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$

- $ f \neq 0$ means that for some $x \in\mathbb{R}, f(x)>0$
- $\| f \|_{L^p} > 0 $ should imply something stronger. Is it true that $\| f \|_{L^p} > 0 $ if and only if there exists some nonzero-measure measurable set $E$ such that $|f|>0$ on $E$?

(I am sure this is a duplicate but I wasn't able to find the same question)

Comment: $f\neq 0$ pointwise includes the case where $f\neq  0$ on a set of measure zero. $\|f\|_{L^p}>0$ implies that $f$ is nonzero on a set of positive measure.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, the two notions are equivalent.

Comment: To be clear, "$f\stackrel{C(\Omega)}{=}0$" and "$f \stackrel{L^p(\Omega)}{=}0$" are simply two different definitions. The first implies the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; if $\|f\|_p>0$ then $f>0$ on some positive measure set, since otherwise $f=0$ a.e. and hence $\|f\|_p = 0$. Conversely, if $\|f\|_p = 0$ then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Just an observation: $\|f\|_p = 0 \iff f = 0\ \text{a.e.}$ is one requirement for $\|\cdot\|_p$ to be norm.